# Avoiding universal references in a proper implementation of Scott Meyer's More Effective C++ Item 22: "Consider using op= instead of stand-alone op"?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, overload-resolution, effective-c++

I am trying to follow Scott Meyers' advice in Item 22 of More Effective C++: "Consider using `op=` instead of stand-alone `op`". He suggests that we could create a template for `operator+`, so that all classes that implement `operator+=` automatically get `operator+`:

```
template<class T>
const T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
{ 
    return T(lhs) += rhs; 
}
```

Now, in Item 25 of Effective Modern C++, there is an example (pg. 172) of matrix addition, where overloads of `operator+` with rvalues are suggested, because if you know that `lhs` or `rhs` are rvalues, you can use them to store the result, preventing useless copies of possibly huge matrices. So I added the overloads:

```
template<class T>
T operator+(T&& lhs, const T& rhs)
{ 
    return std::move(lhs += rhs);
}

template<class T>
T operator+(T const& lhs, T&& rhs)
{ 
    return std::move(rhs += lhs);
}

template<class T>
T operator+(T&& lhs, T&& rhs)
{ 
    return std::move(lhs += rhs);
}
```

The problem here is that `T&&` is a universal reference, and it ends up capturing everything, so I end up moving from lvalues, which is undesired behavior.

So how can I do a proper implementation of `operator+` template?

**Partial solution using pass by value:** I also read Item 41: "Consider pass by value for copyable parameters ..." from Effective Modern C++, so I tried to writing my own version like this:

```
template<class T>
const T operator-(T lhs, T rhs)
{
    return lhs -= rhs;
}
```

But this misses the optimization opportunity when rhs is an rvalue, since in this case, I won't use rhs to store the result. So this is only a partial solution.

Comment: You can always make use of something like Boost.Operators when implementing the classes, or even `std::rel_ops` if it floats your boat.

Comment: Can you provide an example with how it's messing up iterator arithmetic? This should be the least preferred overload of `operator-` and I [cannot reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c441546a1a2ce904).

Comment: @Barry. Thanks for the minimal example. Turns out I am getting squiggly lines from CLion, but it does compile! So this is really an issue with CLion's editor. Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: @Barry Completely rewrote the question to address a different but related issue (no harm done since I had no answers).

Comment: N.B. `rhs += lhs` assumes addition is commutative, which isn't true for e.g. `std::string`

Comment: @JonathanWakely Want to post your answer?

Comment: @JonathanWakely That's not a problem. I am considering only cases where addition is commutative.

Answer (score 5):

I think your problem is that you're trying to combine C++03 advice (write a generic `operator+`) with good C++11 advice (overload `operator+` for rvalues), and the two pieces of advice are not necessarily compatible.

The generic `operator+` that you want to write is tricky to do correctly with forwarding references, but you could follow the same approach as the original and create a temporary, moving from `lhs` if it's an rvalue, by using `std::forward` ("universal references" are now known as *forwarding references* and that should give you a clue that the best way to deal with them is usually `std::forward` not `std::move`):

```
template<class T>
    T operator+(T&& lhs, const T& rhs)
    {
        T tmp{ std::forward<T>(lhs) };
        tmp += rhs;
        return tmp;
    }
```

Note that this will *only* accept rvalues on the left-hand side, because the other parameter means that `T` will not be deduced as a reference type such as  `X&` but only an object type such as `X`, so the first parameter can only match rvalues.

So we can add another overload for the case where the left-hand side is an lvalue:

```
template<class T>
    T operator+(const T& lhs, const T& rhs)
    {
        T tmp{lhs};
        tmp += rhs;
        return tmp;
    }
```

This might not be completely optimal, because neither overload will re-use `rhs` when it's an rvalue, but as I said in a comment above `rhs += lhs` is not correct unless addition is commutative. If you are happy to assume it commutes then you could improve on this to re-use `rhs` when it's an rvalue (by adding more overloads and more complexity).

Personally I think the generic `operator+` defined in terms of `operator+=` is interesting as an exercise, but not actually very practical, especially when you take move semantics into account.  Writing a custom `operator+` for your type (like the one on p172 of More Effective C++) isn't *that* much work, and you don't have to deal with forwarding references, and you'll know whether addition commutes for that type and whether it's safe to do `rhs += lhs` or not.

Comment: Overloading with `rhs` an rvalue is tricky. I'm not sure how to do it. Just adding `T operator+(const T& lhs, T&& rhs)` results in an overload ambiguity whenever `lhs` *and* `rhs` are *both* rvalues. How to deal with that case? (Remember, you can assume that `+` is commutative)

Comment: You can just use `std::move` instead of `std::forward<T>(lhs)` in `T operator+(T&& lhs, const T& rhs)`, since as you explain, here `lhs` is an rvalue, not an universal reference.